# Mark an object un-AutoRelease in ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

As we all know, object will not dealloc immediately in ARC when no variable refer it. eg,

```
NSObject* obj = [[NSObject alloc] init];
obj = nil;
```

obj will dealloc after a time.(auto release pool drain).

Now, I want the obj dealloc right after it's been set to nil, which means the obj is not in auto-release-pool. But all other obj should work well as before, which means the program is still in ARC mode.

Is there a way, maybe macro or compiler flag, to do this?

Comment: Don't all object will be move in autorelease pool at allocate. For this need use __autoreleasing. For example [NSArray array] will be move in autorelease pool, but [[NSArray alloc] init] not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Amin is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35427869/603977): the object is not in an autorelease pool. `alloc`, which created the object, does not engage a pool. On the other hand, you're right: ARC may not release the object immediately.

There is indeed an annotation you can use to force the release: [`objc_precise_lifetime`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#id42). Adding that to the variable declaration will cause ARC to send `release` as soon as the object is no longer valid in the current scope.

However, Amin is also right that this is not very likely to be what you want. ARC knows what it's doing -- there are optimizations it can't make when you use this annotation -- and unless you know what it's doing too, you should strongly consider just letting it do its job.

Comment: It's exactly what I want. Thanks for your kindness.

Answer (score 3):

First of all: You should not care about early deallocation. This is a strong code smell.

Second: Are you really, really sure, because `-init` does *not* put an object into ARP. Maybe the expression causes a retain autorelease combination, but compiling in release mode should optimize that away.

However, if it is in ARP you can close the ARP as mentioned by Hermann Klecker or – I think this is better – find the reason for being that object in ARP. There is no need for that.